# Including periodic boundary conditions when drawing box of particles

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, simulation

This is essentially a follow-up question to this older [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159484/creating-random-configurations-of-spherocylinders-or-cylinders).

Given a configuration of tubes (or for simplicity cylinders), we draw them in a box using `Graphics3D`, where `Tube` is used for the particles and a `Cuboid` for the box. But in case the system has periodic boundary conditions, how should the drawing be done to include that in the output image? (Such as, one tube crossing one boundary on one side has the rest of it come out by the opposite side). I wonder if there are built-in features in Mathematica that can be used for such visualizations.

Dummy working example where we have some tubes sticking out of boundaries: a cubic box of 150 (in units of tube diameter which is set to one and length of tubes is 50), containing 6 tubes with following coordinates: (format: for each tube, we have two sets of coordinates for its end-points and its diameter.)

```
tubescoords = {{{36.5609, 76.3166, -54.0265}, {11.6599, 
54.1491, -16.7634}, {1}}, {{-36.2328, 11.7653, 
68.2118}, {-81.3504, -5.47683, 
55.2849}, {1}}, {{69.8237, -64.7285, -9.43758}, {67.6299,
-14.7808, -10.0801}, {1}}, {{-60.2174, 59.2337, 68.1819}, {-17.1851, 
65.5134, 43.5083}, {1}}, {{34.2708, -41.4081, 
33.4426}, {-1.21881, -23.1799, 
63.5793}, {1}}, {{-91.5513, -44.999, -71.719}, {-54.1793,
-76.8396, -62.2584}, {1}}}
```

So the box is:

```
cube = Cuboid[-150/2 {1., 1., 1.}, 150/2 {1., 1., 1.}];
```

And to draw everything:

```
Graphics3D[{
  CapForm[Round], Tube[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@@ tubescoords, 
  Blue, Opacity[0.1], cube
 }, 
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a simple example scene so that other users can play around with it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher good idea, please see the edit.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher apparently `Mod` is sometimes used for these purposes, e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/3d-random-walk-with-periodic-boundary-conditions/13154

Comment: I thought so. The problem with that is that your `Tube`s won't cross the boundary after applying `Mod` - `Tube`s follow always the shortest path between the end points and since the box is convex... So you have to create "mirror" points for `Tube`s and `Line`s that cross the boundary of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create copies of the tubes using `GeometricTransformation`, and then use the `PlotRange` to cut off what lies outside the boundary.

Here I'm adding a coloring to the tubes so that it's clear which tube stubs belong to each other.

```
tubescoords = {{{36.5609,76.3166,-54.0265},{11.6599,54.1491,-16.7634},{1}},
  {{-36.2328,11.7653,68.2118},{-81.3504,-5.47683,55.2849},{1}},
  {{69.8237,-64.7285,-9.43758},{67.6299,-14.7808,-10.0801},{1}},
  {{-60.2174,59.2337,68.1819},{-17.1851,65.5134,43.5083},{1}},
  {{34.2708,-41.4081,33.4426},{-1.21881,-23.1799,63.5793},{1}},
  {{-91.5513,-44.999,-71.719},{-54.1793,-76.8396,-62.2584},{1}}};
cube = Cuboid[-150/2 {1., 1., 1.}, 150/2 {1., 1., 1.}];
plotRange  = Thread@(List @@ cube);
dimensions = Subtract @@@ plotRange // Abs;
tubes = Tube[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@@ tubescoords;
(* adding in a coloring for visualizing periodicity *)
tubes = Thread[{RandomColor[Length @ tubes], tubes}];
transformations = TranslationTransform /@ Table[
    Sequence @@ {
      ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0}, n -> -dimensions[[n]]],
      ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0}, n -> dimensions[[n]]]
      },
    {n, 3}];
transformedTubes = GeometricTransformation[tubes, transformations];
Graphics3D[{CapForm[Round], tubes, transformedTubes, Blue, 
  Opacity[0.1], cube}, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> plotRange]
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Does this approach work for any of the boundaries crossed for the 3D box?

Comment: I believe so - I try rotating it with my mouse to verify.  The code to generate the transformations could probably be written more clearly, to make it plain that I'm doing 6 translation transforms: $\{\pm dx, \pm dy, \pm dz\}$.

Comment: I think `Quotient[RegionUnion @@ (Point[{#1, #2}] & @@@ tubescoords) // RegionBounds, 150, -150/2]` tells you how many translates you need in each direction to tile a region covering the whole.  (In case the paths extend farther than one box away.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 very interesting! I was wondering, I know it s in 3D so may be harder, but is it possible to also draw next to the box it's first (nearest) periodic images? For example like [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions#/media/File:Limiteperiodicite.svg) (but it s 2D).

Comment: @user929304 You see one box because the `PlotRange` restricts the view to one box. So my first thought is to enlarge the `PlotRange` by ± one box, and see if you can adjust the graphics, if needed, to show what you want to illustrate.

Comment: @MichaelE2 how can we modify the plotrange here? What I imagined was to replicate the box (with its current state) attached to each side (face) of the main box.

Comment: @user929304 The translates are already there in Jason's code. They're just cut out of the picture by the `PlotRange`.  Start with `PlotRange -> All`, but you might want to modify `plotRange` in the code to suit your purposes.