# How to get a NearestNeighborGraph[] for a given radius with periodic boundaries?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geometry, nearest

I'm wondering if there's a way to use [`NearestNeighborGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) with periodic boundaries, using all nearest neighbors within some radius.

I am aware of similar custom functions, [like this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33988/imposing-a-periodic-boundary-condition-in-nearest-neighbour-search), but I want to simply use the built-in `NearestNeighborGraph`.

```
radiusOfInteraction = 0.25;
myNeighborGraph = 
 NearestNeighborGraph[
  RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}], {All, radiusOfInteraction}]
```

[image]

How could this be generalized to 3D?

Again, I don't want a customized function (which exist already), I'm just wondering if one could do it with a slight modification/application of the built-in `NearestNeighborGraph`.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the same `DistanceFunction` from that answer in the `NearestNeighborGraph`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 3D points, and using the same `DistanceFunction` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33988/imposing-a-periodic-boundary-condition-in-nearest-neighbour-search). Since it's a 3D graph, you can move around it. I also added a `Manipulate` just like in that answer to visually inspect that the periodic `NearestFunction` was working properly:

```
SeedRandom[1];
box = {{2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}};
pts = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[box], 200];
boxfn[x_, b_] := Mod[x, Subtract @@ b, -0.5 Subtract @@ b]
dist[a_, b_, box_] := Norm@MapThread[boxfn[#1, #2] &, {b - a, box}];
nf = Nearest[pts, DistanceFunction -> (dist[##, box] &)];

radius = 0.25;

(* verify the periodic nf is working *)
Manipulate[With[{near = nf[{x, y, z}, {n, radius}]},
  Graphics3D[{
    Point[pts],
    PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{x, y, z}],
    Red, PointSize[Large], Point[near]
    },
   PlotRange -> box,
   ImageSize -> 250]],
 {x, 2, 3}, {y, 2, 3}, {z, 2, 3},
 {{n, 8}, 1, 20, 1}]

(* generate the graph of nearest 3 elements within radius *)
g = NearestNeighborGraph[pts, {3,radius}, DistanceFunction -> (dist[##, box] &), 
  DirectedEdges -> False, GraphStyle -> "LargeGraph"]
```

[image: nearest graph]

The 2D case requires very little modification:

```
SeedRandom[1];
box = {{0, 1}, {0, 1}};
pts = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[box], 100];
boxfn[x_, b_] := Mod[x, Subtract @@ b, -0.5 Subtract @@ b]
dist[a_, b_, box_] := Norm@MapThread[boxfn[#1, #2] &, {b - a, box}];
nf = Nearest[pts, DistanceFunction -> (dist[##, box] &)];

radius = 0.25;

(*verify the periodic nf is working*)
Manipulate[
 With[{near = nf[{x, y}, {All, radius}]}, 
  Graphics[{Point[pts], PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{x, y}], Red, 
    PointSize[Large], Point[near]}, PlotRange -> box, 
   ImageSize -> 250]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

(*generate the graph of all nearest elements within radius*)
g = NearestNeighborGraph[pts, {All, radius}, 
  DistanceFunction -> (dist[##, box] &), DirectedEdges -> False, 
  GraphStyle -> "LargeGraph"]
```

Comment: .@flinty Very nice! I was wondering if one can choose *all nearest neighbors* within a radius. I didn't clarify enough in my original question, but I just edited it. Also, I am still not sure how do you apply the `DistanceFunction` for the 2D case. Could you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: @TumbiSapichu updated with radius. Use `{All, radius}` instead if you want all of them within distance.

Comment: I see. Also, I did find how to make the 2D case, so Nvm on that. Thanks!